# Childwindow set as singleton

Tags: silverlight

Can we have Silverlight's Childwindow set as singleton? If so, can you share me a pseudo code to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question would be way??

But you Can simplest way is to Simple in your App.cs

public static ChilldWindow MYGLOBAL_CHILDE_WINDOW = new SomeIMplementation()

and you can access it from everywhere App.MYGLOBAL_CHILDE_WINDOW.Show() -- to Display it